# How do I print Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I am new comer in Crystal report  printing. Any one suggest me best way of Crystal report print in C# Desktop Application With Example(Source code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want users to just print when they want to?

If so, just enable the print option on the CrystalReportViewer control.

Otherwise the answer provided by kashif is the programmatic way.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CrystalReport1 rpt = new CrystalReport1();
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("data source=localhost;initial catalog=acc;uid=sa;pwd=fantastic;");
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = "select EmpNo, EName from Emp";
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    dt.Clear();
    da.Fill(dt);
    rpt.SetDataSource(dt);
    rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

```
private void PrintForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument cry = new ReportDocument();
    try
    {
        cry.Load(@"C:\Reports\CRYPT.rpt");//your report path
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Your Stored Procedure", con);
        sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Doc_No", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Globlevariable.PrintDocNo;
        DataSet st = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(st, "DATA");
        cry.SetDataSource(st);
            cry.PrintToPrinter(1,false,0,0);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add more details, to explain the key parts of your answer?